# Please help me to understand lightning-cli getinfo more

Tags: core-lightning

I have now clightning running for a month. I watch very often lightning-cli getinfo

Here I found in the first three weeks:

```
"msatoshi_fees_collected": 0
```

A week ago it changed to

```
"msatoshi_fees_collected": 1445
```

and since today:

```
"msatoshi_fees_collected": 50483
```

Now my questions:

1. I believe it is my earnings resulting from using one of my 36 channels. Which one(s)?
2. I want to know my channel info including name, address of nodes and fundings on both ends.
3. Is there a skeleton for a python program available that could fetch info and put it into a table like an excel sheet?
4. I got this message:

> I created a channel with you. If any of your channels to
>   TrueVision.club, LightningTo.Me, or blindedbythelight has all local
>   balance and no remote balance, then I can help equalize those balances
>   for you. Doing so would also mean my channel to you would have local
>   and remote balances more equalized so there wouldn't be a need for you
>   to create a channel back. It requires a bit of coordination so I
>   understand if you'd rather not. Feel free to create a channel back if
>   you want.

Frankly, I don't understand it. What should I do? How can I see what happen here? RENE, I need your help ;-)

bye

Ronald

Answer (score 2):

First of all yes these are your earnings from routing. You can check `lightning-cli listforwards` to get a list (in json) to see through wich channel routings have been attempted and settled or failed. In particular you can analyze the routing fees per channel from the output of that command.

If you are interested in channel balances you can use `lightning-cli listfunds` to see how much balance is on which side of the channel.

As for the message you received someone offered you to balance their channels through you by asking how your capacity is organized on particular channels. You can find that information with the above mentioned listfunds command. You also have the power to share this information. Morally you should have the consent of your channel partners.

As for python: Checkout my [Hack a LAPP video series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXVDwRnU7_I&list=PLaRKlIqjjguB_MxPhs5Fj8g2YX56D4N5l&index=2&t=0s) or my git repo [for the code of that LAPP](https://github.com/renepickhardt/HackALapp/blob/master/startServer.py) that shows how to interact with the Lightning rpc interface.

most important lines will be:

```
from lightning.lightning import LightningRpc
rpc_interface = LightningRpc("~/.lightning/lightning-rpc") 
print(rpc_interface.listforwards())
print(rpc_interface.listfunds()["channels"])
```

If you know python it should be easy to adapt to xls output

Comment: Please provide a link to the specific episode, or code, don't advertise an entire series. Also if possible it'd be nice to include the relevant code here, in order to avoid cross-referencing things that might disappear.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I will do that in the way you suggest - like I usually do - once I don't have a mobile client but a real interface.

Comment: No problem, judging from your other extensive responses this felt a bit different :-)